# How can I use the CodeIgniter Output Compression properly?

Tags: codeigniter

It says not to "echo" when using it. So how do I put in variable in my views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By not using echo it means in your libraries, models, and controllers. Your views are after the output buffer has been called by the output class. you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the codeignitor documentation....

VERY IMPORTANT:  If you are getting a blank page when compression is enabled it
 means you are prematurely outputting something to your browser. It could
 even be a line of whitespace at the end of one of your scripts.  **For
 compression to work, nothing can be sent before the output buffer is called
 by the output class.**